# Rails 4 + Jasmine: How do I require spec files in spec/javascripts/e2e/?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jasmine

I'm starting to integrate Angular in my project and I want to add Jasmine tests. This is my `spec/javascripts` folder tree:

```
./
├── e2e
│   └── products_scenarios.js
├── foo_spec.js
└── support
    └── jasmine.yml
```

When I run tests using `rake spec:javascript`, it only runs the test in `foo_spec.js`. This is my jasmine.yml file:

```
# # path to parent directory of src_files
# # relative path from Rails.root
# # defaults to app/assets/javascripts
# src_dir: "app/assets/javascripts"
#
# # path to parent directory of css_files
# # relative path from Rails.root
# # defaults to app/assets/stylesheets
# css_dir: "app/assets/stylesheets"
#
# # list of file expressions to include as source files
# # relative path from src_dir
# src_files:
#  - "application.{js.coffee,js,coffee}"
#
# # list of file expressions to include as css files
# # relative path from css_dir
# css_files:
#
# # path to parent directory of spec_files
# # relative path from Rails.root
# # defaults to spec/javascripts





spec_dir: spec/javascripts




#
# # list of file expressions to include as helpers into spec runner
# # relative path from spec_dir
# helpers:
#   - "helpers/**/*.{js.coffee,js,coffee}"

# list of file expressions to include as specs into spec runner
# relative path from spec_dir
# spec_files:
#   - "**/*[Ss]pec.{js.coffee,js,coffee}"
#   - "**/e2e/*[Ss]pec.{js.coffee,js,coffee}"

# path to directory of temporary files
# (spec runner and asset cache)
# defaults to tmp/jasmine
# tmp_dir: "tmp/jasmine"
```

How would I require everything inside of the `e2e` folder? Or even better, what is the usual folder structure for Jasmine tests in a Rails project?

Answer (score 1):

Default setting for `spec_files` is:

```
spec_files:
- "**/*[Ss]pec.{js.coffee,js,coffee}"
```

Rename `products_scenarios.js` to `products_scenarios_spec.js` and required spec will run. All files with `spec` or `Spec` inside a name will be treated by jasmine as specs.